# How to derive training data for maltparser classifier from conll file

Tags: parsing

Could anyone explain how does the maltparser convert the dependency trees from a CONLL file to a series of transitions in order to train its classifier ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter, such as the ClearNLP [C2DConvert](https://code.google.com/archive/p/clearnlp/wikis/C2DConvert.wiki) for this, which takes PTB trees (*constituency parses*) and converts to *dependency parses* in CLEAR style, or ConLL (TSV), format, which Malt and ClearNLP and other parsers use.

This will convert this:

```
((S (NP-SBJ (NP (NNP Pierre)
                (NNP Vinken))
            (, ,)
            (ADJP (NML (CD 61)
                       (NNS years))
                  (JJ old))
            (, ,))
    (VP (MD will)
        (VP (VB join)
            (NP (DT the)
                (NN board))
            (PP-CLR (IN as)
                    (NP (DT a)
                        (JJ nonexecutive)
                        (NN director)))
            (NP-TMP (NNP Nov.)
                    (CD 29))))
    (. .)))
```

to this

```
1       Pierre  pierre  NNP     _       2       nn      _
2       Vinken  vinken  NNP     _       9       nsubj   _
3       ,       ,       ,       _       2       punct   _
4       61      0       CD      _       5       num     _
5       years   year    NNS     _       6       npadvmod        _
6       old     old     JJ      _       2       amod    _
7       ,       ,       ,       _       2       punct   _
8       will    will    MD      _       9       aux     _
9       join    join    VB      _       0       root    _
10      the     the     DT      _       11      det     _
11      board   board   NN      _       9       dobj    _
12      as      as      IN      syn=CLR 9       prep    _
13      a       a       DT      _       15      det     _
14      nonexecutive    nonexecutive    JJ      _       15      amod    _
15      director        director        NN      _       12      pobj    _
16      Nov.    nov.    NNP     sem=TMP 9       npadvmod        _
17      29      0       CD      _       16      num     _
18      .       .       .       _       9       punct   _
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to code my own implementation of the maltparser. To train such a parser, I believe that I need to convert the training data to a series of correcy transitions (SHIFT, LEFT-ARC, RIGHT-ARC, REDUCE) in order for my oracle to learn the best transition given each configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an oracle finding algorithm. Basically, given the gold standard dependency tree, the oracle finding algorithm tells you what is the next optimal action on a certain state. From the beginning state, you repeatedly apply the optimal action to your state and you can achieve the final state at last.

Different transition systems have different oracle finding algorithms. For the arc-standard system, see Figure 3 in `Nivre (2008), Algorithms for deterministic incremental dependency parsing`: http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/coli.07-056-R1-07-027. In this figure, the precondition rows actually say if your current state satisfy the condition, you can do LEFT-ARC, RIGHT-ARC, or SHIFT.

For the arc-eager system, see Figure 5 in the same paper.